# What is the best way to seed 20.000+ torrents

Tags: scalability, bittorrent

What is the best (most stable) way to seed 20.000+ torrents on 1 server?

Comment: Other than hiring a good legal team? ;-)

Answer (score 3):

There's also S3 so you don't have to buy all of that hardware:

http://carltonbale.com/how-to-create-and-seed-a-torrent-download-on-amazon-s3

Answer (score 1):

The number of torrents you seed really doesn't matter. You could seed a million torrents on a ca. 1997 server quite easily if you wanted to. The metric that really matters is how many active clients do you expect to be active and checking in at any one time. The server proposed in my 1997 example clearly would have a very difficult time dealing with anything more than a very low number of clients.

Answer (score 0):

A fault-tolerant raid array, redundant power supplies, tested and proven hardware, redundant uplinks and downlinks (internet!), and plenty of money to throw at anything from new hardware to legal expenses.

The short answer, in my honest opinion? The best way is not to. ;)

Comment: legal expenses ? torrent != illegal.